# When I use the rich library to add colour, why does it affect the symbols around it? Is there a way to stop this from happening?

Tags: python, rich

**What am I trying to do?**

I am using the `rich` library to print words out in different colours.

I have come up with the following program to do so:

```
from rich import print as rprint

rprint('[[green]1[/green]] Create new password')
print('[2] See existing passwords')
print('[3] Exit')
```

Output:

> [image]

**My Problem**

As you can see on the image above, the square brackets which surround `1` are a brighter in color compared to the ones beneath it `2 & 3`. Is there a way to make the square brackets all the same color (grey) instead of a white?

Thanks in advance.

**Note:**

I am aware that this does not hinder how the program works but I like things to be aesthetically pleasing and this is really bugging me for some reason.

Also, I was just testing how I could go about changing colours using `rich`, but I'm open to suggestions on other ways do this.

Comment: how do user know whether he's at `1` or `2` or `3` if there is no such distinction?

Comment: im not sure what you mean...

Comment: Are you expecting the solution with the `rich` package only ??

Comment: i was just testing how i could go about changing colours using rich but im open to suggestions on other ways to go about it :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rich performs highlighting on the output, for numbers, strings, data etc. In your example it is highlighting braces, which can be helpful when you print data structures.

You can disable this feature if you construct a Console object and set `highlight=False` on the print method.

Here's an example:

```
from rich.console import Console
console = Console()
console.print('[[green]1[/green]] Create new password', highlight=False)
```

See the docs on [highlighting](https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/latest/highlighting.html) for the details.

Comment: ah the man himself! thanks for the answer! that works now. thanks again :D

Answer (score 0):

As the op is open to other ways, here is my way of doing..

Initiate a class with [standard terminal color codes](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/whitedevops/colors).

```
class bcolors:

    ResetAll = "\033[0m"

    Bold       = "\033[1m"
    Dim        = "\033[2m"
    Underlined = "\033[4m"
    Blink      = "\033[5m"
    Reverse    = "\033[7m"
    Hidden     = "\033[8m"

    ResetBold       = "\033[21m"
    ResetDim        = "\033[22m"
    ResetUnderlined = "\033[24m"
    ResetBlink      = "\033[25m"
    ResetReverse    = "\033[27m"
    ResetHidden     = "\033[28m"

    Default      = "\033[39m"
    Black        = "\033[30m"
    Red          = "\033[31m"
    Green        = "\033[32m"
    Yellow       = "\033[33m"
    Blue         = "\033[34m"
    Magenta      = "\033[35m"
    Cyan         = "\033[36m"
    LightGray    = "\033[37m"
    DarkGray     = "\033[90m"
    LightRed     = "\033[91m"
    LightGreen   = "\033[92m"
    LightYellow  = "\033[93m"
    LightBlue    = "\033[94m"
    LightMagenta = "\033[95m"
    LightCyan    = "\033[96m"
    White        = "\033[97m"

    BackgroundDefault      = "\033[49m"
    BackgroundBlack        = "\033[40m"
    BackgroundRed          = "\033[41m"
    BackgroundGreen        = "\033[42m"
    BackgroundYellow       = "\033[43m"
    BackgroundBlue         = "\033[44m"
    BackgroundMagenta      = "\033[45m"
    BackgroundCyan         = "\033[46m"
    BackgroundLightGray    = "\033[47m"
    BackgroundDarkGray     = "\033[100m"
    BackgroundLightRed     = "\033[101m"
    BackgroundLightGreen   = "\033[102m"
    BackgroundLightYellow  = "\033[103m"
    BackgroundLightBlue    = "\033[104m"
    BackgroundLightMagenta = "\033[105m"
    BackgroundLightCyan    = "\033[106m"
    BackgroundWhite        = "\033[107m"
```

**Your Program**

```
print(f"[{bcolors.Green}1{bcolors.ResetAll}] Create new password")
print('[2] See existing passwords')
print('[3] Exit')
```

**Output:**

> [image]

Comment: Thanks for that! It works fine now :D But i will wait for a little more time before accepting your answer as there may be other ways of doing this

Comment: although this worked im going to accept Will Mcugans's answer because it is solved more easily. However, thanks for the answer :D